# Cant use toArray after Filter and Pluck a collection laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5, collections, laravel-collection

I need to display a list of category label from a filtered collection seperated by comma in blade views.

The code looks like this

```
{{$data->categories->filter(function ($value) {return $value->type_id == 1;})->pluck(['label'])->toArray()}};
```

This error is when I use `toArray()`

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

I need the result in array to use it with implode to display the list seperated by comma

```
{{implode(', ',$data->categories->filter(function ($value) {return $value->type_id == 1;})->pluck(['label'])->toArray())}};
```

Expected result to display:

```
Car, Truck, Cheap
```

The collection

```
[{"id":80,"type_id":1,"label":"Car","pivot":{"data_id":6060,"category_id":80}},
{"id":45,"type_id":1,"label":"Truck","pivot":{"data_id":6060,"category_id":45}},

{"id":75,"type_id":8,"label":"Cheap","pivot":{"data_id":6060,"category_id":75}}]
```

If I dont use filter / where the collection, I can use toArray()

Any idea why using filter/where collection causing toArray() error?

Comment: I think the problem is not in this piece of the code. Are you using this result somewhere in your blade views?

Comment: yes its in blade views

Comment: Are you trying to output the array directly somewhere in your views? Can you post this code?

Comment: I am trying to display the implode(....) result so the list will be seperated by comma. the code is in the question

Comment: Have you tried debugging what the output of the collection is without the `implode`?

Comment: toArray() giving me the error, if I stop at pluck('label') without toArray(), it return ['Car','Truck']

Comment: Put it into @php tags and hen check gotten array. Although, best way would be to do that kind of logic in controller and pass variable to view (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toArray` after `pluck`. In fact you need to use it if you are going to treat the results of `pluck` as an array. For instance if you do:

```
$data = Model::where({condition})->pluck();
```

and then try to use `$data` as an array like:

```
if (in_array($someEntity, $data) {
     //entity is in data
}
```

It will give you error, you will need to convert the pluck result in array like so:

```
$data = Model::where({condition})->pluck()->toArray();
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: the problem is toArray() giving me the error. since implode() need result in array